# Find the position of the last specified character in a string in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know the position of the last "\" in the code below:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
CharacterSearch = "\"
x = InStr(Path, CharacterSearch)
Do Until InStr(x + 1, Path, CharacterSearch) = 0
x = InStr(x + 1, Path, CharacterSearch)
Loop
Debug.Print x
```

Where you loop to find all `\` until `InStr` is 0, i.e.,until the last backlash is found.

Comment: Working fine thanx!

Comment: The answer given by Darren Bartrup-Cook is simpler, my answer use loops and his an in-built function of Excel just once.

Answer (score 3):

You use `INSTR` to find the location of one string within the other.

For example:
`C:\MyPC\SomeOtherPath` - the backslash is in position 3 as shown in this code.
`INSTR("C:\MyPC\SomeOtherPath", "\")`

This doesn't give you what you want though - you want the reverse of this.  Luckily VBA gives that with `INSTRREV`:

`INSTRREV("C:\MyPC\SomeOtherPath", "\")`

This returns the position of the last backslash - in position 8.

Comment: No. In the code in your answer `x = InStrrev(Path, CharacterSearch)` would give the last position.

Comment: Oh ok, understood it wrong. Where it was position 8 from last to first, but it would be position 14 on this logic.